# I cannot find how to record a macro in Powerpoint 2013

Tags: powerpoint, visual-studio-macros

I want to be able to change the default Playback start option from On Click to Automatically, and move the audio horn icon from the middle of the slide to the lower right, and make sure that Timings is selected.

I can only create the container...can't figure out how to get VB to record my actions?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks :) joan

Answer (score 0):

You can't record macros any longer.  The recorder went away several versions ago (2003 was the last one that had it).  And it probably wouldn't have recorded any of the animation stuff in any case.